# Can I convert a SQL DataType of DateTime to a DateTimeOffSet in EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have a large database where we do a lot of TimeZone conversions. I am slowly converting the database to use DateTimeOffSet datatypes, but that's something I can't do accross the board. Too much change.

I can however change the code, and since I know that all my dates are stored in UTC in the database, I would like to just use the DateTimeOffSet object in .NET.

How can I get EF to do the conversion on the fly for me?

I have tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<DateTimeOffset>()
                .Configure( c => c.HasColumnType( "datetime" ) );
```

But I'm getting the error

> (37,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.DateTimeOffset[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=]' of member
>   'ModifyDate' in type '{ObjectType}' is not compatible with
>   'SqlServer.datetime[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=3]' of
>   member 'ModifyDate' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.{ObjectType}'.

Comment: simular question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389954/entity-framework-mapping-datetimeoffset-to-sql-server-datetime

Comment: @ArsenMrkt - If I follow the accepted answer in that thread, I get a new error: "The property 'CreateDate' is not a declared property on type '{ObjectType}'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one approach you might consider:

First, define this following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DateTimeKindAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly DateTimeKind _kind;

    public DateTimeKindAttribute(DateTimeKind kind)
    {
        _kind = kind;
    }

    public DateTimeKind Kind
    {
        get { return _kind; }
    }

    public static void Apply(object entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
            return;

        var properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || x.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?));

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var attr = property.GetCustomAttribute<DateTimeKindAttribute>();
            if (attr == null)
                continue;

            var dt = property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?)
                ? (DateTime?) property.GetValue(entity)
                : (DateTime) property.GetValue(entity);

            if (dt == null)
                continue;

            property.SetValue(entity, DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt.Value, attr.Kind));
        }
    }
}
```

Now hook that attribute up to your EF context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized +=
            (sender, e) => DateTimeKindAttribute.Apply(e.Entity);
    }
}
```

Now on any `DateTime` or `DateTime?` properties, you can apply this attribute:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DateTimeKind(DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime Bar { get; set; }
}
```

With this in place, whenever Entity Framework loads an entity from the database, it will set the `DateTimeKind` that you specify, such as UTC.

Now, you said you want to start switching over to `DateTimeOffset` types.  You can take advantage of the fact that `DateTime` has a one-way implicit conversion to `DateTimeOffset` that will take the `.Kind` into account.  In other words, you can do this:

```
DateTimeOffset BarDTO = foo.Bar;
```

Even though `foo.Bar` is a `DateTime`, this will work.  Because the kind is set to UTC, the offset will be set to zero in the `DateTimeOffset`.

Of course, you could always do this in your model with something like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public DateTimeOffset BarDTO
{
    get { return Bar; }
    set { Bar = value.UtcDateTime; }
}
```

I'm sure you can come up with variations on this to suit your needs.  The main thing is that whatever property is mapped to the field, the type must match.

Comment: Not *Exactly* what I was hopping for, but a considerable step in the right direction.