# Comparison of DateTimeOffset in UTC via EF LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to make the following call:

```
itemsCount = await _db.Disposals
                      .Include(d => d.ItemIds)
                      .Where(d => d.OrganizationId == SelectedOrganizationID &&
                                  d.CreateDateTime.UtcDateTime > greaterThanUtc &&
                                  d.CreateDateTime.UtcDateTime < lessThanUtc)
                      .SelectMany(d => d.ItemIds)
                      .CountAsync();
```

The SQL `CreateDateTime` field is a `datetimeoffset` type in SQL. The problem, I am 99% sure, is that an equivalent of this: `CreateDateTime.UtcDateTime` does not exist in SQL, so it has to be done on the backend, rather than in the db. I can bring all the data to the backend like this and then do a comparison:

```
itemsCount = _db.Disposals
                .Include(d => d.ItemIds)
                .AsEnumerable()
```

but this is obviously a poor solution and messes with async. What are my options here to get the count asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force all DateTime objects coming out of the database to be specified as UTC you'll need to add a T4 transform file and add additional logic for all DateTime and nullable DateTime objects such that they get initialized as DateTimeKind.Utc

1) Create the .tt file for your .edmx model

2) Open the .tt file and find the "WritePrimitiveTypeProperty" method.

3) Replace the existing setter code. This is everything between the ReportPropertyChanging and the ReportPropertyChanged method callbacks.

Here is the step by step instructions:

http://www.aaroncoleman.net/post/2011/06/16/forcing-entity-framework-to-mark-datetime-fields-at-utc.aspx

Comment: I saw the answers explaining that on here - I need it for this particular instance though, not overall.