# Entity Framework: how to include protected Collection<>?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got a collection of addresses which can contain multiple addresses for a Customer (delivery, invoice, etc.)

Now, I'm trying to use `.Include(s => s.Addresses)` on my Customer class. Addresses and the derivative DeliveryAddress are defined like this:

```cs
protected virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses
{
   get { return _addresses ?? (_addresses = new Collection<Address>()); }
   set { _addresses = value; }
}

[NotMapped]
public Address DeliveryAddress
{
   get { return GetAddress(AddressType.Delivery); }
}

private Address GetAddress(AddressType type)
{
   return Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type == type);
}
```

Since it's a protected property, I've found a solution for this on [Mapping but not exposing ICollections in Entity Framework](https://owencraig.com/mapping-but-not-exposing-icollections-in-entity-framework/)

I Also found the following post, but this is about mappings instead of includes:
[How to map a protected property in EF 4.3 code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311954/how-to-map-a-protected-property-in-ef-4-3-code-first)

Here they add the following to the class containing the protected property `public static Expression<Func<Parent, ICollection<Child>>> ChildrenAccessor = f => f.ChildrenStorage;`.

So I've added the same to my Customer class like so:
`public static Expression<Func<Customer, ICollection<Address>>> AddressesAccessor = f => f.Addresses;`

And then i'm able to use the include with `Include(Customer.AddressesAccessor)`
This works great for mappings, but I'm not getting it to work with the Include method. It keeps telling me the following:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Web.DataAccess.Customer' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Addresses'.

When I change the signature of the Addresses property from `protected` back to `public` all works fine.

Does anyone know how to make this work for protected collections?

Comment: It looks like you need it to be `public`.  So why do you want it to be set to `protected`?  What's the problem with leaving it as `public` since you want other classes to be able to access the property?

Comment: The collection was already present on the customer. I want to add some extra `public`properties that expose the addresses by type, instead of having to do a linq query on the collection all the time. And with those extra `public` properties, there's no need for the collection to be `public` too anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this out, and it worked great for me.  A sample project can be found at https://github.com/codethug/EF.Experiments/blob/master/EF.Test/SubCollectionTests.cs with tests that pass.

Are you using the Fluent Mapping syntax, like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasMany(Customer.AddressesAccessor)
            .WithRequired();
    }
```

Or are you using Data Annotations?

I found that when I used Data Annotations instead of the Fluent Mapping, I would get the exception you found.  But using Fluent Mapping made everything work without trouble.

I'm guessing that what's happening is when you use Data Annotations, there is a lot of convention being used to figure out what should be considered a Navigation Property, and since the Addresses property is protected, the convention says that it shouldn't be a Navigation property.  However, if you use the Fluent Mapping, you are explicitly telling EF that Addresses should be a Navigation property.

If you really want to use Data Annotations, you can probably code up some custom conventions, but I'm not too familiar with how that could be done.